# Why do I get "Items Cannot be installed or removed until package catalog is repaired"?

Tags: software-center

I'm new to Ubuntu. I’m unable to install anything on the Ubuntu Software Centre.

It just keeps giving me `Items Cannot be installed or removed until package catalog is repaired`.

If I click on *repair* it just gives me:

```
Package operation failed 
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 174380 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libjpeg8:amd64 (from .../libjpeg8_8d-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8d-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8', which is also in package libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 1.2.1-0ubuntu2
configured to not write apport reports
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8d-1_amd64.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-hpijs:
 printer-driver-hpijs depends on libjpeg8 (>= 8c); however:
  Package libjpeg8:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing printer-driver-hpijs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-hpcups:
 printer-driver-hpcups depends on libjpeg8 (>= 8c); however:
  Package libjpeg8:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing printer-driver-hpcups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hplip:
 hplip depends on printer-driver-hpcups (= 3.12.6-3.1); however:
  Package printer-driver-hpcups is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing hplip (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/138734/software-center-items-cannot-be-installed-or-removed-until-package-catalog-is

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Open terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

Type the following: 
clear package database (just in case some of them were corrupted)

```
sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get -f install
```

then run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and run this again

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

if you get something like

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

then it failed. Else, you can try downloading the packages from Ubuntu Software Center

Btw, did you tick all options in Software Sources Options?:

[image]

Comment: the sudo apt-get -f install does not work I get an error
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8d-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: okay, let's go down a step. try
`sudo dpkg --force-all --remove libjpeg8_8d-1_amd64.deb`
and then
`sudo apt-get -f install`
which should install libjpeg8_8d-1_amd64.deb as a missing dependency